# "Trouble is now closer than earlier"

Tags: grammaticality

> Trouble is now closer than earlier.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? What is the right way to say this?

Comment: You may as well rephrase it as "Trouble is now closer than ever".

Answer (score 2):

It's understandable but slightly awkward in American English. A more idiomatic sentence would be:

> Trouble is now closer than before.

Or a more formal version:

> Trouble is now closer than it was before.

Comment: Thank you. Can I just say trouble is now closer? does that make any sense

Comment: @Manasa "Trouble is now closer." doesn't really stand by itself well as a sentence because it is unclear what you mean by "closer" [closer than *what*?]. Unless the context makes it very clear that you are comparing time frames ["now" and whatever "earlier time" you mean], you should specify by saying, e.g., "T. is now closer *than before*."

Answer (score 2):

I think "**Trouble is now more imminent**" is better.

That way, the "than before" can be omitted due to it being obvious from the context.

Although it's technically not incorrect to use *closer* to refer to nearness in a non-spatial sense, I've personally never heard it used like that.